# Is reputation awarded per post basis or per vote basis?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I did some research on how reputation is calculated. I am aware that when an action that effects reputation is taken, the denormalized integer that represents reputation, stored in the users table, is incremented or decremented accordingly.

What I would like to know is how this is done:

1. Is it per vote? So that the net effect of one vote is added or subtracted form the reputation score.
2. Is it per post? So that the votes on a post a re-tallied, and the value of reputation accrued on the affected post is applied to the denormalized reputation column?

Comment: Judging by what it looks like in the reputation audit, and most importantly by how Community Wiki posts work, I'm inclined to believe that this is on a per-vote basis. But... I'm not an expert on this stuff, so I'm only positing this in a comment.

Comment: Oh, **I guess was too trigger-happy?** I don't actually understand the question, so its probably **not** a duplicate of [How does "Reputation" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).... Sorry!

Comment: @Arjan, I wanted to know the specific method of calculation as opposed to a general over view of how "reputation works"; in that, I wanted to know whether the votes are audited per post, then applied, or if the reputation difference is simply on the fly: "here's a plus 10" or "here's a minus 2" after each vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's on a per vote basis.

For every<sup>(*)</sup> up-vote you receive on an answer you gain 10 points.
For every<sup>(*)</sup> up-vote you receive on a question you gain 5<sup>(+)</sup> points.
For every down-vote you **receive** you lose 2 points.
For every down-vote you **give** you lose 1 point.

But clearly votes are applied to posts so if the post no longer exists (it's been migrated or just simply deleted) then the votes don't count any more and your reputation will change (more than likely in a downward direction) if your reputation is recalculated for any reason (see Diago's comment).

* Votes received after you hit the reputation cap (200 points from **voting**) don't award any more reputation
+ It's still 10 points for a question up-vote here on Meta.

Comment: Just a note that your reputation will only change for deleted posts once a reputation recalculation occurs, and not at the point of the post being deleted. A recalculation can also be triggered by the vote fraud scripts if detected.

Comment: Don't forget, you also get +2 points for accepting another person's answer